# set adds duplicated items

Tags: flutter, dart, set

When I'm adding the same item to the set it gets duplicated if this item contains a list.

ex:
‍‍‍‍‍

```
main() {
  print('equales ${Foo([]) == Foo([])}');

  Set<Foo> set = {};

  set.add(Foo([]));
  print("set.length = ${set.length}");
  set.add(Foo([]));
  print("set.length = ${set.length}");
}

class Foo {
  List<int> ints;
  Foo(this.ints);
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Foo &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          listEquals(ints, other.ints);
  @override
  int get hashCode => ints.hashCode;
}
```

output:

```
equales true
set.length = 1
set.length = 2
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does changing the function declaration to take a dynamic parameter allow this to work?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: Use this package for a simpler and better data structure comparison https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Comment: I know this package and I don't think it will help in this case

Comment: the two items are already equal and the list sees them as equal the problem is with the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Set` uses `hashCode` to check for equality unlike the `List`

and by default in dart `hashCode` of the list returns its reference which is useless in this case.

so you must use `DeepCollectionEquality().hash(list)` or if the order is not important `DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().hash(list)` for the `hashCode` implementation.

and `DeepCollectionEquality().equals(list)` or if the order is not important `DeepCollectionEquality.unordered().equals(list)`

so the working code for the example above is:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Foo {
  List<int> ints;
  Foo(this.ints);
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is Foo &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              DeepCollectionEquality().equals(ints, other.ints); //the same as listEquals(ints, other.ints)
  @override
  int get hashCode => DeepCollectionEquality().hash(ints);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is true, but each time you passed the new List [] to Set with different hashcode. Instead of check list's hashcode, check equality with an enum class.

```
main() {
  print('equales ${Foo([]) == Foo([])}');
  print('list -> ${[] == []}');

  Set<Foo> set = {};

  set.add(Foo([], fooType: FooType.HAPPY));
  print("set.length = ${set.length}");

  set.add(Foo([], fooType: FooType.HAPPY));
  print("set.length = ${set.length}"); 

  set.add(Foo([], fooType: FooType.SAD));
  print("set.length = ${set.length}");
}

class Foo {
  List<int> ints;
  FooType fooType;

  Foo(this.ints, {this.fooType});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Foo &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          listEquals(ints, other.ints);

  @override
  int get hashCode => fooType.hashCode;
} 

enum FooType { HAPPY, SAD }
```

output:

```
equales true
list -> false
set.length = 1
set.length = 1
set.length = 2
```

Hope it will be useful

Comment: they are equal, look at the edited answer, I don't want to compare references.

Comment: the list is filled by uses so simply adding enum won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your hashCode method is incorrect, https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html:

> Hash codes must be the same for objects that are equal to each other according to operator ==.

List does not override the default == and hashCode which means they're based on identity:

```
main() {
  print('${[] == []}'); // false
  print('${[].hashCode == [].hashCode}'); // false
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I use `listEquals` in my code, if you use `listEquals` it returns true.

Comment: but you are right, it looks like the `set` unlike the `list` uses `hashCode` to check for equality.

Comment: We learn from Smalltalk that if you override equals, you also have to override hashCode, which you did not do.